# Scanner not stopping to read input

Tags: java

In order to make my program more streamlined (Without try and catch everywhere), I tried to create a seperate method just for getting data. I have one for Doubles, and Strings, as well.
For some reason, when I try to use this method, it is completely ignored, and passed by like a comment. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
public int inputint(){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
     int variable = 0;
     boolean valid = true;
     do{
        try{
           if (variable >= 0 && valid){
           }
           else if(valid){
              System.out.print("Please enter positive values only: ");
           }

           valid = true;
        }
           catch (InputMismatchException e){
              System.out.print("Please enter numerical values only: ");
              sc = new Scanner(System.in);
              valid = false;
           }
     }while (!valid || variable < 0);
     return variable;
  }
```

Comment: Don't edit your question to incorporate the answer - that's what the *answer* is for. And you don't need to change the title to 'solved'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, you're code is insanely hard to understand. (or could just be me I guess)

But if you look at your code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
     int variable = 0;
     boolean valid = true;
```

You are creating the Scanner object, but nowhere in the method are you actually using it.

The next few lines,

```
if (variable >= 0 && valid){
       }
```

both of those conditions are met. So with nothing in the brackets, no code is executed. So from there, it just returns the value of the variable, which is 0.

So you need to actually use your Scanner class to grab an integer. Which I believe, though I'm not sure, the method for that is

```
Scanner.nextInt();
```

Edit: From the JavaDocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

You can simply use

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

to read an integer from the Scanner.

Comment: Sorry about that,
my try and catch usually gets really hard to follow, so I try to keep it in this easier method.

Comment: @kryyn I don't understand why you're using try, catch at all. Maybe your question isn't explained well enough or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `variable` is assigned `0` and the `valid` variable is assigned `true`. Consequently, the `while (!valid || variable < 0)` expression will always be evaluated to `false` and the do-while loop will only be executed once (without the Scanner ever being created).

I guess that you would like to read the user input before checking the variable `variable`, so  you would probably like create the Scanner and read the input before doing the `if (variable >= 0 && valid)` check.

Side note, you can probably skip the `valid` variable and use `variable =`[sc.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)`;`, compare with @Austin's answer.